# Установка selectItem после удаления элемента

Tags: c#, c++, winforms

Имеется простой listBox, с него пользователь может удалить выбранные элементы, т.е.

`listBox2.Items.Remove(listBox2.SelectedItem);`

Каким образом можно установить `SelectItem` то есть таргет на следующий или предыдущий элемент после удаления текущего? Прошу прощения, глупый вопрос, но второй день не дает покоя.

Comment: WinForms или WPF?

Comment: @ VladD, WinForms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну например так:

```
var selectedIndex = listBox2.SelectedIndex;
if (selectedIndex != -1)
{
    listBox2.Items.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);
    if (selectedIndex >= listBox2.Items.Count)
        listBox2.SelectedIndex = listBox2.Items.Count - 1;
    else
        listBox2.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex;
}
```